# Spatial temperature distribution function caused by a steady flame

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

Consider a flame on a gas stove, it is clear that at very far away points the temperature difference caused by it being turned on is negligible. It seems intuitive to me that the rate of change of temperature change with respect to radial distance from center of flame is increasing.

For example, if I am at a far away point and I move my thumb a bit closer to the center of the flame, then I don't feel much temperature difference but if I am right next to the flame, even small motions cause drastic temperature changes.

But, this doesn't make sense to me, because if we have a function which has a finite maxima(like some fixed temperature at center of flame) then magnitude of the gradient of temperature should get smaller as we get closer to the flame.

Hence, **is the temperature of center of flame (blue part), approaching infinity or is it that actually the gradient's magnitude shrinks as we get closer to the flame? If it is the latter which is true, then why is it that the temperature decays at very far away points from the source?**

Please answer with a scientific reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As almost always when something diverges, you have to refine your description when you go close to the center.
When away from the flame, you can consider it as a punctual source of energy.
When you are into the flame itself, it won't be the same, as the source term will decrease with the size, it will "flatten" the divergence.

Same thing with the electric field divergence for a punctual charge, which becomes smooth considering a small volume containing a volume distribution of charge, a classic example of Gauss’s theorem.